# Some questions on log4j configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have few basic questions about log4j that I couldn't find exact answers after googling around:

1. Where do System out, System err, e.printStackTrace() statements get written if no `ConsoleAppender` is configured in log4j? In my application I have seen some of these going into root logger file while others go in different log files. (Note that each statement gets logged into only one file since I have set `additivity=false` for all the loggers). What can be a possible reason?
2. What if `appender-ref` is not configured for a logger? Which one gets picked up? See `com.mypkg` from this block of log4j configuration xml (This configuration is working fine but I am unable to figure out how this logger would work):

   `<logger additivity="false" name="com.mypkg">
       <level value="error"/>
   </logger>
   <root>
       <appender-ref ref="root" />
   </root>`

Any guidance would be appreciated.